# How to copy selected columns from a dataframe to another based on a column condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say if I have a `df` with columns `A,B,C,D`.
I wanted to copy `df` to `df1` columns `A` and `B` only based on a condition column `C = 1`.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: `df1 = df.loc[df['C'] == 1, ['A', 'B']].copy()` ?

Comment: Or maybe `df1 = df[['A', 'B']].query('C == 1')` ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Scott for your reply.

The first option worked!!!

The second option is giving error 'expr must be a string to be evaluated, <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> given
Code : temp1 = df[['Music', 'Pop', 'Rock']].query(df.Rock == '1.0')